# Using random choice module to copy from one list another with condition in python

Tags: python

I have a list, say `list_1 = [5,12,22,37,65,100]`, now I want to copy the elements of this list to another list say list_2 which will also have the same number of elements, i.e in this case = 6. I just want to run a loop for 6 times and generate 6 different random numbers and depending on the values of random numbers I want a take an element from list_1 and copy that to list_2 using the logic :`for the generated random number take the next higher number from the list.`

But the catch is one number is `not allowed more than n/2 times`. In this case, no number can come from `list_1 more than 3 times`. If the 1st 3 generated random numbers are : 55, 61 and 58 then the first 3 elements of `list_2` will be = `[65,65,65]`, so 65 can't be copied anymore.

Below is the code:

```
import random
from random import choice

# choice module gives the choice to pick a random number from a range avoiding some sub range

list_1 = [5,12,22,37,65,100] 

# list_1 indicates the list of all cumulative sums

print(list_1)
list_2 = []

# list_2 is initially an empty list

n_items = len(list_1)

# n_items holds how many elements are there in the cumulative sum list
# random.seed(0)
for _ in range(n_items):
    rand_number = random.randint(1, 100)
    
    # generates a random number between 1 to 100
    
    print(f"Generated random number: {rand_number}")

    for i, number in enumerate(list_1):
        if number > rand_number:
            n_same_numbers_in_list2 = sum(l2i == number for l2i in list_2)
            # Keeps track of the numbers those are getting inserted
            print(f"{n_same_numbers_in_list2+1} is the count for the value")

            if (n_same_numbers_in_list2+1) <= n_items/2:
                number_to_append = number
                print(number)
            else:
                lower_bound = list_1[i-1] if i > 0 else 0
                upper_bound = number
                number_to_append = choice([i for i in range(1,100) if i not in range(lower_bound,upper_bound)])
            list_2.append(number_to_append)
            break

print(list_2)
```

Here it is creating problem in `number_to_append = choice([i for i in range(1,100) if i not in range(lower_bound,upper_bound)])` this condition. That is whenever an element is trying to enter more than 3 times then it is simply generating another random number which can be outside the `list_1`.

Below I am attaching one such sample output.

```
[5, 12, 22, 37, 65, 100]
Generated random number: 84
1 is the count for the value
100
Generated random number: 75
2 is the count for the value
100
Generated random number: 90
3 is the count for the value
100
Generated random number: 82
4 is the count for the value
Generated random number: 52
1 is the count for the value
65
Generated random number: 13
1 is the count for the value
22
[100, 100, 100, 39, 65, 22]
```

Here though 39 is not in the list_1, still it is getting printed in the output file.

Answer (score 0):

> Here though 39 is not in the list_1, still it is getting printed in the output file.

Here is no check to presence of number inside `list_1` when `else` running.

Fast and simple solution is to add `while` loop (very bad performance):

```py
            else:
                lower_bound = list_1[i-1] if i > 0 else 0
                upper_bound = number
                number_to_append = None
                while number_to_append not in list_1 or number_to_append == number:
                    # I changed i to m because i already used as enumerate index
                    number_to_append = choice([m for m in range(1,100) if m not in range(lower_bound,upper_bound)])
```

However there is other logic problems in your code and it is overcomplicated. Here is possible code:

```py
import random

input_list = [5, 12, 22, 37, 65, 100]

# use real randoms
#randoms = []
#for _ in range(0, len(input_list)):
#  randoms.append(random.randint(1, 100))

# or reproduceable randoms from your example
randoms = [84, 75, 90, 82, 52, 13]

result_list = []

input_list.sort()

banned_nums = {}

for random_num in randoms:
  n = None
  for i, v in enumerate(input_list):
    if v > random_num:
        if v in banned_nums and banned_nums[v] >= len(input_list)/2:
            continue
        else:
            n = v
            banned_nums[v] = banned_nums.get(v, 0) + 1
            break
  if n is None:
    result_list.append(-1)
  else:
    result_list.append(v)

print(result_list)
```

You didn't say anything about what number we should append if "good" numbers in `list_1` were ended (for example, if random numbers will be `[99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99]`), so I used `-1` as `Good number not found`:

```
[100, 100, 100, -1, 65, 22]
```